# Strange loading CPU by background worker process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have such loop in background worker, which cause restoring of my on-screen keyboard when user choose some "edit" control.

```
    private void bwAutoShow_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr focused_temp = IntPtr.Zero;
        SetBoolDelegate d_setWindowState = new SetBoolDelegate(SetWindowState);
        int foregroundWindowHandle;
        uint remoteThreadId;
        uint currentThreadId;
        StringBuilder lpClassName = new StringBuilder(100);
        String cn;
        while (autoShow)
        {
            try
            {
                foregroundWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
                remoteThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindowHandle, 0);
                currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
                //AttachTrheadInput is needed so we can get the handle of a focused window in another app
                AttachThreadInput(remoteThreadId, currentThreadId, true);
                //Get the handle of a focused window
                focused_handle = GetFocus();

                if (focused_handle != focused_temp)
                {                        
                    GetClassName(focused_handle, lpClassName, 100);
                    cn = lpClassName.ToString().ToLower();
                    if (cn.IndexOf("edit") != -1)
                    {
                        Invoke(d_setWindowState, new System.Object[1] { true });
                    }
                    focused_temp = focused_handle;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception oException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Błąd ogólny procesu auto wyświetlania klawiatury.\n" + oException.ToString(), "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                throw oException;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
    }
```

delay = 300;
After run application everything is ok, CPU is 0%, but when this loop is active the CPU load is growing. After 10 minutes is ca. 3-5% and CPU frequency is 100%.
RAM load is permanent. After one hour move the mouse's cursor is not constant - jumps :) What is wrong with this loop?

Comment: I assume `AttachThreadInput` also needs to be detached. I would bet that not doing so is going to result in another set of events being delivered for every call, so, for example, call it 5 times on the same thread and you wind up processing 5 copies of each event.

Comment: From [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956(v=vs.85).aspx): "Keyboard and mouse events received by both threads are processed by the thread specified by the idAttachTo parameter until the threads are detached by calling AttachThreadInput a second time and specifying FALSE for the fAttach parameter."

Comment: Thank you guys :) It was it.